# why the classes have to be inside the other class?

Tags: java, swing

```
public class AreaDeRectangulo extends JFrame {

    public static final int WIDTH = 640;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 480;

    public JLabel AltoL, AnchoL, AreaL, PerimetroL;
    public JTextField AltoTF, AnchoTF, AreaTF, PerimetroTF;
    public JButton Calcular, Salir;

    public BotonDeCalcular cbHandler;
    public BotonDeSalir ebHandler;


    }

    public class BotonDeCalcular implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            double alto, ancho, area;

            ancho = Double.parseDouble(AnchoTF.getText());
            alto = Double.parseDouble(AltoTF.getText());
            area = ancho * alto;

            AreaTF.setText(" " + area);
        }
    }

    public static class BotonDeSalir implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            AreaDeRectangulo rectObj = new AreaDeRectangulo();
        }

    }
}
```

Why the classes "BotondeCalcular" and "BotondeSalir" have to be created inside the main class? are they like a mini-classes?
PD: it gives me an error if I try to separate the classes

Comment: Can you clarify? They don't *have* to be made in your main class, but what do you mean by a syntax error upon "separation"?

Comment: What error do you get if you try to separate the classes?

Comment: look it is supossed to do an action once the button is pressed in the actual application and it works perfectly like that (the classes inside) but if i separate it, it doesnt do anything.

Comment: It doesn't do anything is not the same as it gives you an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because they are *inner classes* and use the features available to inner classes. Let's look at `BotonDeCalcular`:

```
ancho = Double.parseDouble(AnchoTF.getText());
```

This uses a field called `AnchoTF`, declared in the *outer* class. In essence, that line is equivalent to the more verbose:

```
ancho = Double.parseDouble(AreaDeRectangulo.this.AnchoTF.getText());
```

If you want to move those classes to separate files, you'll need to hold an instance of `AreaDeRectangulo` that you pass in by constructor.

Comment: So, if i want to separate it i have to "import" somehow the AreaDeRectangulo class?

Comment: @SvelterEagle No, an import is not usually necessary. However, you need to make sure that your classes have a reference to your `AreaDeRectangulo`.

Answer (score 2):

They are called `Nested Classes` (some call them `Inner Classes` or other names)

As for why the author chose to do so, the [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) provide some suggestions.

> Compelling reasons for using nested classes include the following:
>
> It is a way of logically grouping classes that are only used in one place: If a class is useful to only one other class, then it is logical to embed it in that class and keep the two together. Nesting such "helper classes" makes their package more streamlined.
>
> It increases encapsulation: Consider two top-level classes, A and B, where B needs access to members of A that would otherwise be declared private. By hiding class B within class A, A's members can be declared private and B can access them. In addition, B itself can be hidden from the outside world.
>
> It can lead to more readable and maintainable code: Nesting small classes within top-level classes places the code closer to where it is used.

These are design decisions that developers make. There is no hard reason why a class must be defined inside another class.